# Is it safe to put a bow on a puppy?

Tags: dogs

My puppy is a 13 week Goldendoodle and my wife wants to put a clip on bow clipped to her fur. Is this safe and ok for the puppy? The clips don't weigh much at all so they won't be weighing her down at all. I've seen other breeds like Shitzus with a ponytail similar to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there's nothing wrong with putting hair clips or hair ties on dogs. They're not poisenous and the hair will not suddenly fall off.

But you should be mindful of the will of your dog and consider possible secondary risks.

- Your dog might not like the hair clip and scratch it off. Make sure the clip doesn't pull any hairs or otherwise makes your dog uncomfortable. If it's just for aesthestic reasons, consider leaving it off if your dog doesn't like it.
- Some dogs are insecure and shy or don't like to be touched by strangers. The added attention a hair tie may pull to them could make them even more insecure or uncomfortable.
- It might fall off and your dog could chew it, possibly swallowing parts and/or injuring itself.
- Your dog might hurt itself if it tries to squeeze through a tight space and the clip gets caught or if a dog scratches it off during play. I'm sure you know how much pulling on single hairs can hurt.

Comment: Also, just to add, make sure her hair is not pulled. That she is not in pain because of the clips